# Automatically Submitting a Form WITH Submit Button Parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am using the following code to submit a form automatically:

```
<form id="reg_form" name="reg_form" method="post" action="../mm2/register.php" >
<input  ..... />
<input  ..... />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.reg_form.submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>
</form>
```

However, the manual way I was submitting it was using the following button:

```
<input type="submit" name="save_user" value="   Register  >> " >
```

The problem is the file where the "action" parameter send the data (register.php) READS THE "name" attribute OF THE SUBMIT BUTTON and executes different code based on whether it sees it or not. 
In other words, I get a different results when I submit using the automatic method or the button.

When I use the submit button, all is well. But when I use the automatic submission method, I get on undesired result.

I DO NOT have access to the "register.php" file to modify this behavior.

Is there any way I can automatically submit a form as if it was sent using a button with a particular "name" attribute?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Add hidden field with the same pairs (name=value) as the submit button

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your form (or replace the button):

```
<input type="hidden" name="save_user" value="   Register  >> " >
```

I guess the register.php requires a POST field named `save_user` to be present, so a simple

```
<input type="hidden" name="save_user" value="ok" />
```

should do the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger click event on your submit button

```
document.getElementById('submitButtonId').click();
```

if you want not to display submit button then you can hide it from css:

```
<input type="submit" name="save_user" id="submitButtonId" value="Register  >>" style="display:none;">
```